# postgis st_linemerge based on attribute

Tags: postgis

I have a postgis table full of very small line segments. I would like to merge them according to an attribute in another field:

```
update line_table set the_geom = ST_LineMerge(the_geom);
```

but how do I do this according to the attribute so that all the small segments with name="west" are joined, and those with name="north" are all joined etc?

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` works with `WHERE` conditions [just like](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) `SELECT`. So it is a simple matter of appending the condition:

```
update line_table set the_geom = ST_LineMerge(the_geom) WHERE name="west";
update line_table set the_geom = ST_LineMerge(the_geom) WHERE name="east";
update line_table set the_geom = ST_LineMerge(the_geom) WHERE name="north";
update line_table set the_geom = ST_LineMerge(the_geom) WHERE name="south";
...
```

Comment: would something like "update line_table set the_geom = ST_LineMerge(the_geom) GROUP BY name;" accomplish the task? guess i've never considered whether or not GROUP BY works in an UPDATE, but it feels too good to be true...

Comment: As can be seen in the linked synopsis, that isn't even part of the valid syntax. If it had any effect, I'd expect it to still merge everything, you'd just have 4 sub-lines of same-named lines in one aggregate line.

Comment: rtfm to me. didn't see the link. asked in hopes there might be a way to avoid writing a function to loop through the name values when there are 4,000 instead of four. Perhaps a WITH RECURSIVE... preceding the UPDATE would do the trick? thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Maybe using FROM line_table AS b WHERE name = b.name would work, I doubt recursion is needed. Even easier if you use a wrapper script in another language.

Comment: However, creating a new table and inserting rows with a INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... GROUP BY ... should work fine.